# How to remove the first sentence of a text file as string before the dot?

Tags: java, string

I need to take the content of a news without the published time in the first sentence.

What i have in my text file:

> Updated January 21, 2016 09:31:19. While there is an argument to be made about modern batting wickets and boring matches, sometimes they give us spectacles like this.. First, Australia surged gloriously to 6 for 348. Second, for the bulk of India's reply, the touring side looked like it would reel that total in.. Finally, Australia crashed back into the game in a late flurry of wickets to win.. . Three centuries, 13 sixes, some hectic overs. It is true that the modern limited-overs game often reduces bowlers to bowling machines, and it was no less true in this contest.. But occasionally the quality of sublime batsmanship makes you willing to accept that inequity is not always iniquity..

And the result i expect is:

> While there is an argument to be made about modern batting wickets and boring matches, sometimes they give us spectacles like this.. First, Australia surged gloriously to 6 for 348. Second, for the bulk of India's reply, the touring side looked like it would reel that total in.. Finally, Australia crashed back into the game in a late flurry of wickets to win.. . Three centuries, 13 sixes, some hectic overs. It is true that the modern limited-overs game often reduces bowlers to bowling machines, and it was no less true in this contest.. But occasionally the quality of sublime batsmanship makes you willing to accept that inequity is not always iniquity..

My current code to pick the content of the news url, the content is the text above.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");

        for (Element p : paragraphs) {
            String content = p.text() + (". ");
            System.out.print(content);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\content.txt", true));
            out.println(content);
            out.close();
```

Where i should put the code i need to fix the "content" before write it into file ?

Comment: *"Where i should put the code"* In an own method which can be called in your `for` loop. Luckily this was the only question here.

Comment: The ohter question i already posted on the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you need to put a filter in the for loop (I'm assuming you want to remove the first line from every element in paragraphs). You can either implement a new function which takes p.text() as an argument and delete the first sentence from it or (definetely easier) you can use java prebuilt substring method; you find the first occurrence of the dot and then you substring from it. In a nutshell, you should find the first occurrance using indexOf and then you can substring  from it

```
String tmp = p.text();
String content = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf('.')+1) + (". ");
```

Comment: A code example is generally preferred to a simple description.

Comment: Thank you, i gathered all the paragraph in the news into "content" string and just delete the first sentence. But, your code solved my question.